# How to use Sony Cybershot W830 as a webcam over USB

Tags: usb, webcam, camera, av-cable

I have a Sony Cybershot DSC-W830 point and shoot camera. I'd like to use it as a webcam. I got a AV cable with the camera along with the usuals including USB cable. But my PC does not have a AV port. And, I see people are using this converter cables to do this. The camera has only one port (idk what its called, its a bit smaller than a std mini usb). The AV cable has that on one head and AV pins on other side. So, my question is:

Is it possible to "emulate" AV pins on the USB cable since its practically the same other than the pins on one side.

I know its not the same and kinda dumb but still is it possible

[Its something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJD36.jpg)

*does this question even belong here*

Comment: Short answer, no. Either the camera has the webcam "mode" via software and running on top of a standard USB cable or, in your case, you need a video input card/device in your PC. The cable maybe is similar or the same as a miniUSB connector but that cable is not standard USB or any USB at all. Connectors, jacks and plugs, are just pieces of metal and plastic, they have no intrinsic properties. What makes a "USB connector" a USB is the USB controller and correct wiring, not the connector itself.